# (C#) DataGridView: How to get Selected Count with cells AND rows?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, selected

So I have this [DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFMc1.png)

And This code:

```
if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: More than one value selected");
            return false;
        }
```

It counts correctly to 2 if I have 2 completly selected rows.
But I want to check if **any cells** from 2 different rows or more are selected.

In other words:
**in my picture** my current selection is returning 1 at the moment but i want it to return 2.

Thank you.

Edit after fix: Working code:

```
if(dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.RowIndex).Distinct().Count() > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: More than one value selected");
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the number of rows with selected cells :

```
int count = dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                       .Select(c => c.RowIndex).Distinct().Count();
```

To check if more than one row is selected:

```
var selectedCells = dataGridView1.SelectedCells;
bool check = selectedCells.Count > 0 
         && selectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Any(c => c.RowIndex != selectedCells[0].RowIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fairly standard setup where each column is bound to a property of your backing data object, and each row represents one object, the following should work:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Select(c => c.Item).Distinct().Count()
```

This will return the number of items the different cells are bound to. Since each item has one row that binds to it, it will return the count of every row with at least one selected cell.

Comment: Yeah the dgv is loaded from an Oracle SQL table so it should be good, lemme test.

Comment: VS2017 says there's no definition for Select(). Do i need an using or assembly?

Comment: using System.Linq;

Comment: I wish it was that simple, but `SelectedCells` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` so most LINQ extensions can't be used on it directly.

Comment: My mistake, you're right, the cast you do in your answer will make it usable by linq.